# Input validation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 textbox controls "Low" and "High". High field should not accept a value lesser than Low, I did this validation,

```
<input id="txtLow" class="txtCell" ng-model='data.low'>
<input id="txtHigh" class="txtCell" ng-model='data.high'>
<button id="btnSave"  ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>
<label ng-show="isInvalid()" class="ErrorMsg">High should be greater than Low</label>
```

In my controller,

```
$scope.saveData = function() {
            if (!$scope.isInvalid()) {
                .........
            }
        };
$scope.isInvalid = function () {
            return $scope.data.low > $scope.data.high;
        };
```

This is working fine. But I need to change the border color of textbox to red instead of showing a label message.

Comment: Create class with needed styling and use ng-class="{'your-class' : isInvalid()}"

Comment: Actually the answer provided by @Kutyel is better ;)

Comment: Because ng-class is more for custom things, when validations comes from the "box" in angular.

Comment: Can we show a balloon message at right corner of textbox instead label?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have css file then add this in html like this

```
<label ng-show="isInvalid()" class="ErrorMsg" style='class = red;'>High should be greater than Low</label>
```